# TypeScript Optional function in Interface

Tags: javascript, typescript

Is it possible to create an Interface in TypeScript with optional function?

```
interface IElement {
  name: string;
  options: any;
  type: string;
  value?: string;
  validation(any): boolean; // --> should be optional.

}
```

Comment: I found an answer, i think there is possible to implement optional function like this: validation?: (any) => boolean;

Answer (score 314, accepted):

There are currently three syntaxes that TypeScript allows for function declarations in interfaces:

Using your example of a `validation` function taking 1 parameter (of `any` type) and a `boolean` return value:

```
validation: {(flag: any): boolean};
```

or in the newer syntax:

```
validation(flag: any) : boolean;
```

or an alternative is:

```
validation: (flag: any) => boolean;
```

**Solution:**

so to make it optional with the old syntax is easy:

```
validation?: {(flag: any): boolean};
```

with the second syntax (recent addition - thanks to `@toothbrush`)

```
validation?(flag: any) : boolean;
```

or in the third syntax (as you found):

```
validation?: (flag: any) => boolean;
```

Comment: The way you've written it, `any` is not a type, but is the name of a parameter that is implicitly of type `any`.  Parameters must be named, even on interfaces.  This code will fail to compile if --noImplicitAny is enabled.  It should be something like this: `validation?:(whatever:any) => boolean;` where `whatever` is some reasonable parameter name.

Comment: @NYCdotNet: Yes, I should not have taken the original *as-read*. Corrected :)

Comment: @gone-coding Hi! How do I know if the function is defined or not?

Comment: @IlanOlkies: Same way you test for anything in JavaScript `if (object.validation)` :) It needs to against the object context, so `if (this.validation)` may also be appropriate depending on your circumstance.

Comment: thank you! found this very helpful for optional function props and TS errors :)

Answer (score 3):

**Just like field properties, we can also declare optional methods in an interface, just by placing "?" after the method name**

```
 interface Vehicle{
  run?(): void;
}

class Sedan implements Vehicle {}

class SUV implements Vehicle {
  run() {
    console.log("run run");
  }
}

let suv = new SUV();

suv.run();
```