# How to allow class functions to be nullable

Tags: typescript, oop

I want to allow the class function to be nullable(In short support something like this):

```
class Example {
    a?: string;
    c?: string;
    b() {
        console.log(this.a);
    }
}

let c = (x: Example) {
    console.log('run');
}
c({a: "123"});
```

**Background**:
I've added some presave hook for typeorm due to which most of the code has broken. I'd like to support it without breaking anything.

[Play link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECiAeYC2AHEBTaBvAUNf0YA-AFzQQAuATgJYB2A5gNx4HCnnX3Ov4BGACgCU2XgXzAA9nQiSMAOhCSGAigAsaEeWCEtxAXxyGcGCtGDQAvNAHwyCZGnQjc4qTLnpFygQHIqAK50vrpGOMACWGBkAEQAjABMAMwx%20rpAA)

Comment: `b?() { .... }`? But at that point you should probably have an *interface*, rather than a class.

Comment: That's right @jonrsharpe thank you. Can you please add it as an answer else I'll be doing that

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/27523954/12397250?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53145280/6517383 is the answer that I was looking for since it's not that rated I think that's why I missed it.