# Typescript generics return type issues

Tags: javascript, typescript

I use typescript generics in my project but it seems not work well.

example:

```
interface Test<T, P> {
  a?: (v: T) => P
  b?: (v: P) => void
}

const fn1 = <T, P>(_config: Test<T, P>) => {}

fn1({
  a: (p) => 1,
  b: (p) => {},
})
```

I think `params 'a'` type just like:

`Test<unknown, number>.a?: ((v: unknown) => number) | undefined`

But, actually:

`Test<unknown, unknown>.a?: ((v: unknown) => unknown) | undefined`

I do not know why, someone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Why do you have arrow functions in your interface?

Comment: @Phil Is there a reason why he/she shouldn't, or why it might not be desirable? (genuine question)

Comment: @CertainPerformance I guess I'm missing something (still a relative TS noob) but don't you normally define interface functions like `a?(v: T): P`. Hadn't seen the arrow syntax yet. _Edit:_ ok, found [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27523954)... TIL

Comment: @Phil From what I understand, they are exactly equivalent (you can even do silly looking things like `a?: (this: string, v: T) => P`), so whether one uses `=>` or `:` syntax is only a style choice

Comment: I'm continually surprised by the way you can define things in Typescript. Here's FishToucher's definitions side-by-side with the more 'conventional' definitions: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIJSgewO4FkJgAWmAJgM4A8AKgDTIAKAfMgN4BQyycA-AFzIAKAG78qASmQBeZvQ7IARn0EiGE6ciGZgJNgF82bAPSHkASTLIiKMnAC2KOBaLAybUJFiIUAeQAOYYEwQOAAbfCJSSloGZnZOHmFRCX56AG45RUTVZH5NbXT9IxMAMQBXEAQAoOQSCBhQCBJkUrJQAHMuDBw2BCCyMGQYEABGKWRqOiYBAH1ekHq2-nQsPAJicgmYtVjC4zMnQms7BwOXNhhyysCQQZAAJk2p2aCFpa7ViI3opgk45CgCKUoDcWLoCgZziMKP0oO06CBSrZ5NBGAI-nB+AJfNtkMMaBlMdipDt8boxEA

Comment: I assume you are aware that you can explicitly specify the types: `fn1<unknown, number>({...})`

Answer (score 1):

**This is because in a union an unknown absorbs everything.**

For P in (a) TypeScript infers a type of "number", but then for P in (b) it infers a type of "unknown", just as it does for T in (a).

Therefore, P results in a "number | unknown" (not "number | undefined" as you expected), which results in just "unknown".

If you refer to the TypeScript docs [here](http:////%20In%20a%20union%20an%20unknown%20absorbs%20everything%20type%20T10%20=%20unknown%20%7C%20null;%20//%20unknown), you'll find:

> // In a union an unknown absorbs everything

> type P = unknown | number; // unknown

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not defining the type on this line:
`b: (p) => {}`

Then TS cannot infer the type of P, even though you return it in the above definition for `a`.

Comment: I define the type on `a`:

Comment: `a: (p: string) => 1,`,

TS can infer the type of P: `Test<string, number>.a?: ((v: string) => number) | undefined`.

It's very strange, Is there any connection between T and P?

Comment: It is strange behavior, looks like TS chooses safest typing (least specific). I have written another potential solution using the built-in `ReturnType` type, but requires `a` to exist since I use it as an index type:

`interface Test<T, P> {
  a: (v: T) => P
  b?: (v: ReturnType<Test<T, P>['a']>) => void
}`